# Remove Virtual Enviroment name from CMD

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, python-venv

Everytime you activate a virtual environment it shows the name on cmd or powershell. I want to remove it or just not show it. There is any way?

Example: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks2yt.png)

I'm searching for more than 2 days on every language and I didn't find yet.

Comment: Have you tried `deactivate` inside the shell?

Comment: it seems like you'll have to define your own shell prompt, sort of like [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3505) (vbrh-immalle's comment on sept 7 2019), except they were adding the virtualenv to the prompt

Comment: @StonedTensor i think they mean keep it activated but not mention it is activated in the terminal prompt.

Comment: @actuallyatiger  Makes sense, thanks for clarifying. Definitely seems like you'd have to add your own script to make it work.

Comment: You can try `path/to/pythonX.Y -m venv --prompt '' path/to/venv`. This will still add `() ` as prefix, but maybe that is good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to define a new prompt function to override your current one. Here's an example from the [powershell prompt documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.3)

```
function prompt {
  $identity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
  $principal = [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] $identity
  $adminRole = [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

  $(if (Test-Path variable:/PSDebugContext) { '[DBG]: ' }
    elseif($principal.IsInRole($adminRole)) { "[ADMIN]: " }
    else { '' }
  ) + 'PS ' + $(Get-Location) +
    $(if ($NestedPromptLevel -ge 1) { '>>' }) + '> '
}
```

which will give you a prompt like `[ADMIN]: PS C:\ps-test>` if you run ps as an administrator, or `PS C:\ps-test>` otherwise.

I'd recommend looking at that documentation if you would prefer a different type of prompt.